# CSS background property not working with wamp64

Tags: html, css, wamp, background-image, wampserver

I am trying to add a hero image to my website. I have the image ready and in my desired location, but cannot set  it as a background image for the hero div. I'm using wampserver64.

I have tried using the `background` property shorthand, but have resorted to using `background-image`, `background-size` tags etc.

Here are the relevant parts of my code:

The links in `<head>`

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/12cols.css" type="text/css"media="screen">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/styles.css" type="text/css"media="screen">
```

```html
<div class="hero">
     <h1>Placeholder</h1>
</div>
```

CSS:

```css
.hero {
  background-image: url("../assets/hero-image.png");
  background-position: center;
  background-size: 100% auto;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;

}
```

And my folder structure is as follows:

```
project
     -assets
          -fonts
               font.ttf (etc)
          -hero-image.png
     -styles
          -12cols.css
          -styles.css
     -index.php
     -login.php
     -signup.php
```

I don't get any error messages except for GET `http://project/favicon.ico 404 (Not Found)`

**UPDATE:** Tried testing as an HTML file without using wampserver, but still with no avail.

Also adding a height and width specification to make it look like this:

```css
.hero {
  background-image: url("../assets/hero-image.png");
  background-position: center;
  background-size: 100% auto;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 100%;
  height: 1200px;
}
```

hasn't helped either.

Comment: The code you provided is [working as expected](https://jsfiddle.net/z6rks2o4/).

Comment: It might be specifically related to wamp

Comment: It wouldn't be a wamp issue, if the page is loading, then the code should be working. If this is just straight HTML, you don't even need wamp to test to see if it's working, you can just open the HTML file directly in a browser.

Comment: Its a php file.

Comment: Change the extension to html and open it directly in a browser to rule out wamp

Comment: Still doesn't work

Comment: Then the issue is something other than the code you posted here

Comment: Could you be a little more specific XD?

Comment: No, because I do not have access to your code, so I cannot see what the issue actually is, but there are no issues with the code you have posted here, so if you aren't getting a 404 error on the background image, then there's some other issue with your code.

Comment: I thought you said there was nothing wrong with the code

Comment: Open the console and then network tab and see if you are getting 404 error on image fetching

Comment: Try adding width and height

Comment: @XPD, still not working. Lazar Nikolik: The only error i see is ```GET http://project/favicon.ico 404 (Not Found)```

Comment: What browser(s) are you testing with? Since the issue occurs with plain HTML, have you considered posting an example to jsfiddle or similar so you can demonstrate it not working?

Comment: As usual, a hard reload (Ctrl + F5) seems to have fixed everything!

Comment: can you provide a working example?

Comment: No problem. Am just on the way to school, will do it when I get hone

Answer (score 0):

IMG and CSS are not visible because they are in the same directory. Try deleting **assets**.

```
background-image: url("../hero-image.png");
```